# Changing HTTP code with http.ServeFile

Tags: http, go, server, standard-library

I'm writing a server in Go, and I'm currently implementing error pages (404, 500, etc.) I have files which can be served for these errors, but if I use `http.ServeFile` then I get HTTP code 200 instead of the appropriate code.

Is there a way to change the status code, or do I need to rewrite `http.ServeFile` for this use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading the source I don't see any way to change the status code (other than the method failing which means you won't get your error page served). I think it's implied that if the files is served then it was an `HTTP 200` which isn't entirely unreasonable.

I recommend reading the error page file into a string then using this method; https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Error

EDIT: That may actually not be specific enough for you even. It wants the error message as plain text so what I suggested is likely a misuse. In which case you're left with no useful abstractions to do what you want.

In response to comment, my personal preference would be something more along the line of;

```
func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/sendstrailers", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        resp := &http.Response{
            StatusCode: 404,
        }
        resp.Write(w)
    })
}
```

but you could also just use `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusForbidden)` or whatever if that's your preference. Whatever better suites you needs. My experience would be with preparing response object in a scope different than that of the mux so for that reason I think I prefer the bit above (it makes more sense than having helper methods return unstructured data you then write in to the responsewriter).

Comment: So you recommend using `WriteHeader` and `io.WriteString` directly?

Comment: @Charles that would be one way. Another option is to instantiate an instance of `http.Response` than then do `resp.Write(w)` and it will write the response into the `ResponseWriter`. That was you can explicitly set whatever values you want which is more what I was thinking of.